# Rotate Image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to rotate image inside rotated box in flutter, I know the image is inside the box and because of that it's also rotating with it, but I want to rotate it back "only the image inside the box, I want to  keep the box rotated as it is" as normal.

Here is my current code:

```
body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Transform(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          3.1415926535897932 / 4,
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Image.asset("assets/images/man.png"),
                              decoration: kInnerDecoration,
                            ),
                          ),
                          height: 66.0,
                          decoration: kGradientBoxDecoration,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text("Name Row"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Text("Bottom"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Current output in the simulator:
[image]

What I want to look like:
[image]

Comment: It's the image in the semi diamond shape, I don't think there is a use for it here ...

Comment: do you want container to be in same position?

Comment: I updated the question with how I want it to look like, the drawing is kind of bad but hopefully it's clear. Please take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played a bit and got this code. I put a reverse rotation for the picture and changed the indents.

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final kInnerDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
  );

  final kGradientBoxDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.black, Colors.redAccent]),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50)),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Transform(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          3.1415926535897932 / 4,
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Transform(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                                  -3.1415926535897932 / 4,
                                ),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/image.png",
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 100,
                                ),
                              ),
                              decoration: kInnerDecoration,
                            ),
                          ),
                          height: 100,
                          width: 150,
                          decoration: kGradientBoxDecoration,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50)),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text("Name Row"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Text("Bottom"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate back by using the same but negative value and to `align` the use `transformAlignment: Alignment.center,` I am using `Container`'s `transform`, you can also wrap with `Transform` widget.

```dart
Transform(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
    3.1415926535897932 / 4,
  ),
  child: Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 200, // the size you prefer
        height: 200,
        transformAlignment: Alignment.center,
        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
          -3.1415926535897932 / 4, // here
        ),
        child: Image.asset(...)
```